# Jackson: Serialize an EER specialization

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'm using spring boot with jackson to provide an API.
In my DB there is a generalization/specialization field. That means, I have two fields: a value and a field that defines the data type of the value.

So my entity looks like this:

```
public class Example{
    private String value;
    private String type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

For example with these three entries:

```
"1234";"Integer"
"example string";"String"
"true";"Boolean"
```

Jackson serialize this as follows:

```
[{
    "value": "1234",
    "type": "Integer"
},
{
    "value": "example string",
    "type": "String"
},
{
    "value": "true",
    "type": "Boolean"
}]
```

This is what I expteced, but, I need this:

```
[{
    "value": 1234,
    "type": "Integer"
},
{
    "value": "example string",
    "type": "String"
},
{
    "value": true,
    "type": "Boolean"
}]
```

So, the values should be serialized according to the value of the "type" field.
I know that I can attach a serializer to the "value" field, but I cannot access the "type" field there to know how to serialize the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change your Example class like this if you can :

```
public static class Example {
    private String value;
    private String type;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("value")
    @JsonRawValue
    public Object getRawValue() {
        if("String" .equals(type)){
            return '"'+ value +'"';
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Or you could use deserializer on `Example` class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Example.class, new MySerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(list));
}

private static class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Example> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Example value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                                                                      throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        gen.writeFieldName("value");

        if (value.getType().equals("String")) {
            gen.writeString( value.getValue());
        } else {
            gen.writeRawValue(value.getValue());
        }

        gen.writeStringField("type", value.getType());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
[{"value":1234,"type":"Integer"},{"value":"example string","type":"String"},{"value":true,"type":"Boolean"}]
```

---

**Update**

Here is one way how you could use custom deserializer and default one for every other field:

```
private static class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Example> {
    private static final ObjectMapper internalMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void serialize(Example value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode node = internalMapper.valueToTree(value);

        if (value.getType().equals("String")) {
            node.put("value", value.getValue());
        } else {
            node.putRawValue("value", new RawValue(value.getValue()));
        }

        gen.writeObject(node);
    }
}
```

Will need to have `@JsonIgnore` in your `public String getValue()`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. 
Is it also possible to use the default behavior for all other fields expect of "value" without explicitely define how to handle each field? My entity has a lot of fields and I don't want to list/manage all of them in multiple classes (entity, serializer and deserializer...)

Comment: @Indivon i updated answer with new option and yep you can use default deserialization in your custom deserializer. Give me a min, i'll update the info

Comment: @Indivon updated my post, take a look, probably there are some other option you could try